# Interplay of argument injecting decorators and pytest fixtures

Tags: python, pytest, decorator, fixtures

I have a decorator that can inject an argument into a function, which works fine. However, when I want to use it on a test function, things get messed up with pytest fixtures. Is there any way to fix it?

see this example:

```py
@pytest.fixture()
def my_fixture():
  ...

def auto_asset(name, path: Optional[Path] = None, return_path: bool = True):
    """
    Decorator to automatically retrieve asset and insert path into decorated functions
    signature (default).

    Args:
        name:
        path:
        return_path: insert return path as "path_{name}" in decorated function's signature

    Examples:

        @auto_asset("bead_cal")
        def some_fn(path_bead_cal: Path):
            pass
    """

    def wrap_fn(fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        def wrapped_fn(*args, **kwargs):
            p = load_asset(name=name, path=path)
            if return_path:
                # add asset path to decorated functions signature
                kwargs.update({f"path_{name}": p})
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapped_fn

    return wrap_fn


@auto_asset("calibration", return_path=True)
def test_something(path_calibration, my_fixture):
   ...
```

for this I directly get

```
_pytest.fixtures.FixtureLookupError: ('path_calibration', <FixtureRequest for <Function test_something>>)
```

even setting a breakpoint in the decorator implementation does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you really need to keep the original decorator as it is, I'd simply rewrite it into an **indirect** Pytest fixture. Simplified example (not a complete rewrite of the decorator):

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def my_fixture():
    ...

@pytest.fixture()
def auto_asset(request):
    p = load_asset(name=request.param["name"], path=request.param["path"])
    ...

@pytest.mark.parametrize("auto_asset", ({"name": "calibration", "path": "", "return_path": True},), indirect=True)
def test_something(auto_asset, my_fixture):
    ...
```

To make it more complex and delay calling of `load_asset` which would otherwise happen at the test collection, the fixture could build and return a function instead:

```py
import pytest
from typing import Callable, Optional
from functools import partial
from pathlib import Path

@pytest.fixture()
def my_fixture():
    ...

@pytest.fixture()
def auto_asset(request):
    def _(name, path: Optional[Path] = None, return_path: bool = True):
        p = load_asset(name=name, path=path)
        ...

    return partial(_, **request.param)

@pytest.mark.parametrize("auto_asset", ({"name": "calibration", "path": "", "return_path": True},), indirect=True)
def test_something(auto_asset: Callable, my_fixture):
    path_calibration = auto_asset()
    ...
```